# how to display json vertically (as columns) not horizontally (as rows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I have this json {"heat":"jimmy","mavs":"dirk"}

i want to display them as a table with 2 rows using jqgrid.

| Team | Player |
| --- | --- |
| Heat | Jimmy |
| Mavs | Dirk |

normally the display will be like this with jqgrid

| Heat | Mavs |
| --- | --- |
| Jimmy | Dirk |

Comment: use an HTML table element ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-on-demand service, where work orders are given and people code for you. Someone may very well answer this question before it gets closed, but it reduces the site's usefulness for everyone when they do.

Comment: ok sory di na uulit

Comment: I don't know `jqgrid`, but probably you need to create a function that maps `{ "key1": "val1", "key2": "val2" }` to an array of objects: `[{ team: "key1", player: "val1" }, { team: "key2", player: "val2" }]`. But please read about the [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `Object.entries()` method for this JSON structure if you want to use key as first td for row and value as second one.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) you can see nice example, how to do it.

Welcome to comment for additional help.